# What`s meaning behind this phrase - square quality certification?

Tags: phrase-request

Is there anybody who can provide a clear-cut explanation for the above-mentioned phrase ? Your help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Square is an acronym for:

> Software product Quality Requirements and Evaluations

and is an extensive series of standards with numbers of the form ISO/IEC 250mn. e.g. ISO/IEC 25000, ISO 25010, and ISO/IEC 25010. The porpose of the standard is to address some of the well known human biases that can adversely affect the delivery and perception of a software development project.